# BlenRig 5 - turn off Hand IK parenting

Tags: animation, rigging

working with Blenrig 5, trying to animate a scene with a table. Would love to have the character grab the table, but the hand ik's are parented to the torso, and I'm not seeing a good way to switch that off.

In the arms tab under the extra properties in the addon, I'm seeing a free option for the arm pole targets, which has the functionality I'm talking about... I just can't find it for the hands themselves.

Is there a good way to deal with this, or does Blenrig not support this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

On the Blenrig body picker, where it says arm_L and arm_R just change the hinge to 1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit, attatch a screenshot or the like? At the moment the answer is very brief and a bit hard to understand.