# IK Handles Parented to Hip Controller

Tags: animation

While I'm very familiar with most of Blender's tools, I'm fairly new in regards to using it for character animation so forgive me if I come off as ignorant. Currently I am playing with the Ivan rig and trying to animate a scene for a university assessment, and there is a problem. See, while the hands are on an IK setting, they still appear to be connected to the hip controller, or rather any of the main controllers on the torso for that matter (excluding the neck and head controllers). I am trying to figure out how exactly I am able to separate those IK handles so that when I move the torso, the hands do not follow along and remain where they are.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am also trying to figure out how to attach a prop to a character's hand on a pre-existing rig like this one. I understand you have to go through the bones to do so like in Maya. But I'm not too sure how to do it here. Again, I am ignorant to this so apologies if this is frustrating to some of you professional folks that know what you're doing, haha.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to search for solutions for these issues and yet I still haven't found any that truly sort me out. Any assistance regarding this would be very much appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your first problem will require a look at the file. But your second one can be solved without seeing it. The most straightforward way to attach your props to your rigs is probably to create a **Child Of** constraint. With your prop selected in Object Mode, look for the *Object Constraint* tab in the Properties Panel. From the *Add Object Constraint* dropdown, find and select **Child Of**. For the *Target*, choose your armature. Once chosen, you have access to a new text field for choosing the bone itself within the armature that you want to become the prop's parent. You probably want to make the target the IK handle of the hand in this case. You may notice after choosing a bone in this field that the prop jumps wildly. Press *Set Inverse* to make it return to its original position. When you move the parent, the prop moves as well.

The reason we use a *Child Of* constraint instead of a direct parenting relationship (from the *Set Parent To* menu) is because you can't keyframe changes to direct parenting relationships. But you can keyframe a change to the influence of any constraint, by right-clicking on the **Influence** slider, and setting one. This allows you to turn off the effect of the constraint at will, such as in those cases where the prop is intended to be free of a character's grasp at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've managed to upload the file, although I had to remove a lot of props from the scene just to accommodate the 30MB limit. I hope the file is accessible.

Comment: I don't see any link to your file.

Comment: One thing that might be making it large is the possibility of packed textures. If you have them, you will want to unpack them before sending the file, or else they will remain with the file. I don't need textures to look at problems with the rig.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ZEyoJDvm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZEyoJDvm/)

Comment: Apologies about that. I'm still new to this website and figuring out the kinks. Hopefully that should be accessible now

Comment: This rig too advanced for me to find the solution. I see no evidence that proper IK constraints exist anywhere in the arms, though I know they're there, or else the IK behavior wouldn't exist. I tried unparenting the IK controllers in Edit Mode, which worked to make your hands stay put during hip motion. But the hand IKs won't stretch to stay where they're put if you add extra motion to the hips. They'll only stay where they are until they run out of slack, then continue to follow the hips, which I'm sure you don't want. This appears to be a BlenRig character, which I have no experience with.

Comment: Ahh I understand. I appreciate the assistance either way, so thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Look at this and let me know if it helps. Someone was wanting the same functionality from another BlenRig. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123840/blenrig-5-turn-off-hand-ik-parenting?rq=1